# Import a Actionscript file from a internal package

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'am trying to import an actionscript file in a internal package in my project. From Java and am used to this to like this

```
import Services.myClass.
```

But the IDE doesn't suggest any classes when I type

```
import Services.
```

So how can I import my `AbstractIdManager.as` file? Inside this actionscript file, there is a public class named `AbstractIdManager` which extends `EventDispatcher`

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

I want to use the `AbstactIdManager` class in my View `videochat.mxml`

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ActionScript can automatically refer to those classes in the same package.
To import a class you can use

```
import Services.AbstractIdManager
```

inside the CDATA tag of your mxml file.

Comment: The problem was that the package bracket didn't specify any name of the package on top of the .as file. Problem solved.